# Azure Data Factory to Azure Blob Storage Permissions

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I'm connecting ADF to blob storage v2 using a managed identity following this doc: [Doc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage#linked-service-properties)

When it comes to test the connection with my first dataset, I am successful when I test the connection to the linkedservice. When I try by the filepath, and enter "testfolder" (which exists in the blob) it fails returning a generic forbidden error displayed at the end of this post.
However, when I opt to "browse" the folders in the dataset portal, the folder "testfolder" does show up. But when I select it, it will not show me anything within that folder.

The Data Factory managed instance is given the role of Contributor, granting full access to manage all resources. Is there some other hidden issue or possible way to narrow down the issue? My instinct is that this is something within the blob container since I can view the containers, but not their contents.

Error message:

[image: Error Message1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you don't give the role of azure blob storage.
Please fellow this:

1.click IAM in azure blob storage,navigate to Role assignments and add role assignment.
[image]

2.choose role according your need and select your data factory.
[image]

[image]

3.A few minute later,you can retry to choose file path.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Ok, so the permissions for writing to a blob (Data Storage Contributor) are not contained inside the permissions of Contributor? When I hover over the role of contributor it sounds like it can do anything but assign roles, which we are now showing is not the case.

Comment: Yes.Contributor permit a security principal to manage a storage account,but doesn't  provide access to the blob data.If you want to access blob data,you need to give Storage Blob Data Contributor.You can refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-portal#azure-roles-for-blobs-and-queues).